# Angular combining a http get request with this

Tags: angularjs

I am using `this` instead of `$scope` for an angular app, which is leading to difficulties when I try and access the the result of the `get` request in my controller.

My factory looks like this:

```
app.factory('footballService', function($http) {
    return{
        getAllTeams : function() {
            return  $http({
                    url: 'url',
                    dataType: 'json'
            })
        }
    }
});
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('footballController', function(footballService) {

    var footballController = this;

    footballService.getAllTeams().success(function(data){
        console.log(data); //this data is shown
        footballController.teams = data;
    });

    console.log(footballController.teams); //this is undefined
});
```

The issue is that I want to access the teams outside `getAllTeams()`. Can anyone explain how can I access this variable? I thought by setting `var footballController = this;` would allow me to access this throughout the controller, but I must be misunderstading how it Angular works.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: because you are tried to access the asynchronous data before it is being populated

Comment: @PankajParkar makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getAllTeams()` function is returning a "promise" - the underlying data is not available until the asynchronous call has completed.

You can therefore only safely access that data within a `.then` callback (AFAIK `.success` is deprecated), but it needn't be the same callback as the one in which you assigned the data to the current scope:

```
var promise = footballService.getAllTeams().success(function(data){
    console.log(data); //this data is shown
    footballController.teams = data;
});

promise.then(function() {
    console.log(footballController.teams);
});
```

Comment: makes perfect sense.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald FWIW, I highly recommend that you look at `$resource` - I had been merrily using `$http` everywhere for about a month before I discovered that `$resource` can make RESTful service interaction so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Move your console call into the `success` callback.

```
app.controller('footballController', function(footballService) {

    var footballController = this;

    footballService.getAllTeams().success(function(data){
        console.log(data); //this data is shown
        footballController.teams = data;
        console.log(footballController.teams); //this is populated now
    });
});
```